# Insert Text Ribbon disabled while editing page

Tags: web-part, page-layout, edit

I am having lots of trouble while trying to edit the start page of SharePoint. I am a Site Collection Admin and have full rights on SharePoint Site but I'm not (an no one else) able to add a simple text block as a webpart control.

All other WebParts are working fine, but I cannot find any webpart which let me edit/enter some free text.

So I'm either interested in getting the control enabled or otherwise looking for a webpart (which I can use) which permits me to insert text on the page. :)

Here is how the controls look for me:

[image: disabeld insert text]

Comment: Is this in SharePoint Online? If so you administrator need to take a look at this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-scripting-capabilities-on-or-off-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US for enabling scripting capabilities

Comment: no its actually SharePoint Server 2013

Answer (score 0):

> There are two views to each web part page, the shared or public view,
>   and the personal view.
>
> If you go to the Welcome menu and select "Personalize this page" you
>   will see this message:
>
> ***You are editing the Personal Version of this page***
>
> If you go back to the Welcome menu and select "Show Shared View" then
>   you can add the text on the page.

Please follow below mentioned link to understand the scenario.

[SharePoint 2013: Personalize a page and configure Web Parts to create a personal view.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31454.sharepoint-2013-personalize-a-page-and-configure-web-parts-to-create-a-personal-view.aspx)

Comment: well thats not the point. I'm aware that there are "two" views. but both editing menus behave the same. they are its just a different audience of viewers ;)